# Teradata UNION with additional data

Tags: sql, teradata

Lets say we have two different Table

Table_eBay

```
Id      Product      
 1      SomeProduct-1
 2      SomeProduct-2
```

Table_Amazon

```
Id      Product      
1       SomeProduct-1
2       SomeProduct-3
```

Is that possible to combine like below?

Table_Output

```
Id      Product        isEbay       isAmazon
 1      SomeProduct-1  TRUE         TRUE
 2      SomeProduct-2  TRUE         FALSE
 3      SomeProduct-3  FALSE        TRUE
```

Comment: What do expect the new `Id` to be?

Comment: Not cared about Id.

Comment: Some SO problems right now? I tried to write an answer, but the editor doesn't accept <return> and I don't want to write it all in one line...

Comment: So remove id from the expected result!

Comment: @jarlh (1) try to connect to the site using https:// (2) OP probably means the Id is arbitrary but he still would like an Id column

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, https first seemed to work, but just for a short while. Strange. I've written 1000+ answers and never had this issue before.

Comment: @jarlh, I don't know the source to this issues but I had queries  I couldn't submit due to multiple `SELECT`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      row_number () over (order by Product)                as Id
           ,Product
           ,max (case tab when 'E' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end) as isEbay
           ,max (case tab when 'A' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end) as isAmazon

from        (           select 'E' ,Product from Table_eBay 
            union all   select 'A' ,Product from Table_Amazon
            ) t (tab,Product)

group by    Product

order by    Product
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a full join as below:

```
select 
case when AMZ.product is null then EB.product else AMZ.product end as product,
case when AMZ.id is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end as isEbay,
case when EB.id is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end as isAmazon,
rownum as ID /* alternative take the last char of product */
 from AMAZON AMZ FULL OUTER JOIN EBAY EB ON
AMZ.product = EB.product;
```

Take into account that in your example the product ID = 2 means 2 different products in the tables (i used rownum from Oracle).

Regards,
Sérgio

Comment: (1) Why would you recommend FULL JOIN when the UNION ALL solution is much more clean and perform much better? (2) You should use COALESCE (3) There is no `rownum` in Teradata

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: Of course (2) & (3) are correct, but why do you assume that the `UNION ALL` performs better? This approach avoids the inefficient aggregation of two rows.

Comment: @dnoeth, you are totally right. My mind was somewhere else :-)